# How to debug an issue in my Python code?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I can not get "totalBill" in the last line of my code to print correctly. I am not sure how to make it realize the user input and only use those if constraints.

```js
# Compute and display the customer bill for water usage during the billing period
# Prompt the user to enter 3 values:
#   a. The customers code (a character)
#   b. The customer's beginning meter reading (a positive integer value)
#   c. The customer's ending meter reading (a positive integer value)
#       Process info and display results

customerCode = str(input("Please enter your customer code: "))
begMeter = int(input("Please enter your beginning meter reading: "))
endMeter = int(input("Please enter your ending meter reading:    "))

waterUsed = endMeter - begMeter

if begMeter > endMeter:
    waterUsedTotal = (((999999999 - begMeter) + 1) + endMeter) /10
else:
    waterUsedTotal = waterUsed * 0.1

a = 4000000
b = 0.00025
d = 10000000
e = 0.0005


if customerCode.lower() == 'r' or 'R':
    totalBill = (5.00 + (waterUsedTotal * e))

elif customerCode.lower() == 'c' or 'C':
    if waterUsed <= a:
        totalBill = 1000.00
    elif waterUsed > a:
        totalBill = (1000.00 + (waterUsedTotal * b))

elif customerCode.lower() == 'i' or 'I':
    if waterUsedTotal <= a:
        totalBill = 1000.00
    elif waterUsed > a and waterUsed <= d:
        totalBill = 2000.00
    elif waterUsed > d:
        totalBill = 2000.00 + (waterUsedTotal * b)

print("")
print("Customer code: ", customerCode)
print("Beginning meter reading: ", begMeter)
print("Ending meter reading:    ", endMeter)
print("Gallons of water used: ", "%.1f" % waterUsedTotal)
print("Amount billed: $", "%.2f" % totalBill)
```

Comment: "print correctly" - what does this mean? What's it supposed to do? What does it do?

Comment: i'd suggest ending each 'if..elif' block with a final 'else' to catch all other cases, you're probably  missing an edge case not handled by any of the , or at least init 'totalBill' with a default value

Comment: Please don't remove the code you posted; the answer (which you've accepted as correct) makes no sense without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things that I noticed:

```
if begMeter > endMeter:
    waterUsedTotal = (((999999999 - begMeter) + 1) + endMeter) /10
else:
    waterUsedTotal = waterUsed * 0.1
```

In the first case, waterUsedTotal is an `int`, that is, it is rounded down. In the second case, it is converted to `float`. That is inconsistent.

More importantly, though:

```
if customerCode.lower() == 'r' or 'R':
```

This line is always true, because `'R'` is interpreted as true. And the other cases being `elif`, they consequently never get executed.

What I suspect is that you want something like: If the user entered `'r'` or `'R'`, do this, else if the user entered `'c'` or `'C'` do that, else if the user entered `'i'` or `'I'` do the last thing.

I would suggest either:

```
if customerCode in ['r', 'R']:
```

or

```
if customerCode.lower() == 'r':
```

(The `.lower()` means that it will never be any capital character anyway.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The customerCode.lower part worked, but as far as the part with waterUsedTotal the meter is read in tenths of a gallon and the meter only shows 9 numbers before rolling back to all 0's. Also do you by chance know how I might be able to make this program loop without messing up the entire code?